# hyper-v ubuntu changes to ~/.profile do not take effect even after logout/login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, hyper-v

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on hyper-v using the quick create.

I am trying to set a environment variable that will take effect everytime I log in.

I put the following line:

```
export BOOST_ROOT=$HOME/boost_1_69_0
```

in each of:

```
~/.profile
~/.bash_profile (did not exist by default)
```

one at a time, followed by a log out and a log in.

I then opened a new terminal and issued:

```
echo $BOOST_ROOT
```

The output was a blank line. What am I doing wrong?

If I put it in ~/.bashrc it takes effect, however from what I understand, that is only for new bash terminals and won't take effect for anything that doesn't run in bash, right?

Comment: Maybe the shell is not a login shell? Are you running maybe in gnome-terminal?

Comment: Yes, I am in a gnome terminal. I am a Windows guy and got no idea whats what. Is there a way to get perm env variables that will be picked up in the gnome terminal? Or should I not be using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asking because gnome-terminal has an option (in right-click -> preferences) to treat the shell as a login shell.
If you do not want to mess with that, you could just do this in ~/.profile (be sure to remove ~/.bash_profile):

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]
then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]
    then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This is what my Linux Mint distribution does (and ~/.bashrc doesn't contain much more than just this).